# Do not fire ComboBox SelectionChanged when refreshing from back-end

Tags: vb.net, mvvm, combobox, win-universal-app, selectionchanged

I'm a hobbyist programmer who got stuck on something which should be very simple to accomplish... but I don't see the light :

**Situation** : A simple XAML/MVVM/VB.Net application which gives the user a Combobox with radio stations he can tune into. When selecting a radio station, the application sends the command to tune towards a server for further processing and actual tuning (People with LogitechMediaServer/Squeezebox will be able to picture this quite well :)

**But** : There also exists the possibility that the radio station that is tuned into changes through other means than this application. For this reason a "Refresh" button exists to get the currently tuned into radio station.

The example code is part of a user control with a limited height. Because of this I want to ComboBox to be used as both a selector, as well as a way to provide the current status (which Radio Station is tuned into).

**The Problem** : When Refreshing the status from the server, the SelectionChanged event is fired again, which sends another Tune request towards the server. I don't want this to happen. How can we ensure that the SelectRadioStation() RelayCommand is only fired when the user selects a different radio station, and not when the radio station is updated from the server ?

**Note : Possible but not preferred Solution** : Add an extra textblock which shows the actual Radio Station that is tuned to, and bind that to SelectedRadioStation. Because of the height of the user control I don't really want this, and prefer to only have 1 combobox.

The MVVM Model is like this :

```
Public Class ViewModel
    Inherits ViewModelBase

    Public Property RadioStations As List(Of String)

    Public Property SelectedRadioStation As String
        Get
            Return _SelectedRadioStation
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            _SelectedRadioStation = value
            RaisePropertyChanged()
        End Set
    End Property
    Private Property _SelectedRadioStation As String

    Public ReadOnly Property SelectRadioStation As RelayCommand(Of Object)
        Get
            Return New RelayCommand(Of Object)(Sub(x)
                                                   Await SendSelectedRadioStationToServer()
                                                   Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("ViewModel.SelectRadioStation - executed : {0}", x.ToString))

                                               End Sub)
        End Get
    End Property


    Public ReadOnly Property SetRadioStation As RelayCommand
        Get
            Return New RelayCommand(Sub()
                                        SelectedRadioStation = "Radio 1"
                                    End Sub)
        End Get
    End Property
    Public Sub New()
        RadioStations = New List(Of String)
    End Sub
End Class
```

and the simplified application like this :

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <ComboBox Grid.Row="0" x:Name="RadioStationList" ItemsSource="{Binding RadioStations}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedRadioStation, Mode=TwoWay}">
            <Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
                <Core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="SelectionChanged" >
                    <Core:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding SelectRadioStation}" CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=RadioStationList}"/>
                </Core:EventTriggerBehavior>
            </Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
        </ComboBox>
        <Button Grid.Row="1" Content="Refresh Radio by Querying the server to see to which station the radio actually is tuned to" Command="{Binding SetRadioStation}"/>
    </Grid>
```

And the MainPage OnNavigatedTo (just for testing)

```
Protected Overrides Async Sub OnNavigatedTo(e As NavigationEventArgs)

        myVM.RadioStations.Add("Radio 1")
        myVM.RadioStations.Add("Radio 2")
        myVM.RadioStations.Add("Radio 3")
        myVM.RadioStations.Add("Radio 4")
        myVM.SelectedRadioStation = "Radio 3"

        DataContext = myVM

    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Save a local variable that holds the latest selected item. When a new selection changed event comes in, check the new value with the one that is hold as a local variable. If they are not the same continue the logic that now exist in the selection changed event handler, if they are the same ignore it.